# How do I change the color of my Terminal.App when I log into my production remote on Heroku?

Tags: bash, terminal, heroku

I remember there was an article, or a few, going around about how the author changes the color of the terminal from green (for development) to red (for production) based on the SSH address.

But I am not sure how to replicate that with Heroku console.

Ideally, I would like for it to be say blue, when I do `heroku console --remote staging` and then red, when I do `heroku console --remote production`.

Any suggestions anyone ?

Comment: Does Heroku set anything (like an env var) when working remotely like that? (/me knows nothing of Heroku)

Comment: Yes I guess it could be done via ENV VAR. Thoughts ?

Answer (score 4):

In any file that is loaded as part of the production environment (say, `config/environments/production.rb`), you can put:

```
if defined? IRB
  # whew!
  conf = IRB.conf[:PROMPT][IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]]
  red = "\033[0;31m"
  reset = "\033[0m"
  conf[:PROMPT_S] = "#{red}>> #{reset}" # regular prompt
end
```

The crazy escape characters are ANSI color codes.  The `"\033"` is an escape character, and the rest is a code for a particular color or effect.  You can find a list of other colors and effects [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#colors).  That IRB.conf hash is a global conf for IRB.  You may want to set a few other keys on it - they're documented [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html#UA).

If you're not using Rails (and hence don't necessarily have an environment file), you can always check the current environment by using `ENV['RACK_ENV']`, which should be set to `'production'` on Heroku.

Comment: When I try this, I get this message: `'block in <top (required)>': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` at this line: `conf = IRB.conf[:PROMPT][IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]]` Thoughts ?

Comment: Oh, that's bizarre, they don't seem to be using IRB, but rather a homebrewed client that seems to send ruby code over REST.  I'll take a look and see what's possible, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

I do this by using the Marco Polo gem https://github.com/arches/marco-polo

You can then change your console prompt by setting the heroku config variable MARCO_POLO_APP_NAME. You can take advantage of escape codes to change the color. In my case, I set the production prompt to be white on a magenta background (hard to miss) using this control sequence for the value of MARCO_POLO_APP_NAME

```
[ESC][105;97;1mPRODUCTION[ESC][0m
```

Unfortunately, Stack Overflow won't let me post the escape character itself. You'll have to use Notepad++ and run a Regexp search and replace to replace [ESC] above with \x1B. Then you can copy and paste into the value of MARCO_POLO_APP_NAME in the Heroku console. I couldn't manage to set it at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

untested, but something along the lines of this in your .bashrc or whatever may be what you want (it's not completely safe but you should get the idea)

```
function heroku {
  REMOTE_TERMINAL_THEME_NAME="Solarized Light"
  CURTAB=$(osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to get the selected tab of the front window")
  CURTHEME=$(osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to get the name of current settings of the selected tab of the front window")
  HEROKU=$(which heroku)
  osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of $CURTAB to settings set \"$REMOTE_TERMINAL_THEME_NAME\""

  $HEROKU "$@"
  osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to set current settings of $CURTAB to settings set  \"$CURTHEME\""
}
```

I use it for ssh but it's conceptually the same: override your command with a function that uses osascript to change the terminal settings, then change them back on exit. Switching based on arguments should be relatively easy to add.

Answer (score -2):

You could automate it with bash or batch when you type it aliases are in my opinion one of the best things for cli/terminal devving. Theres an article somewhere where a simple echo command can change your color until you set it back with another echo.

So you could do this with your bashrc if your a nix user.

```
#pretend this is a bunch of prompt setup
#USER ALIASES
alias heroku-staging="export     PS1="\e[0;34m[Heroku Staging]$]" && heroku console --remote staging"
```

Then just type heroku-staging

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/